# Make button active only when first slide is active - Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, slider, swiper.js

I need a button to be active only when first slide is active. I tried this code, but it doesn't work properly - button becomes disabled just always. What is wrong?

```
if ($("#aslide").attr("swiper-slide-active")) {
     //
} else {
    $("#acceptbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Way:

Use **Swiper API** event `slideChange` (Event will be fired when currently active slide is changed) `-AND-` `realIndex` (Index number of **currently active slide** considering duplicated slides in loop mode) .
https://swiperjs.com/api/

```
/* swiper events */
swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
  console.log("slide changed - current slide is: " + this.realIndex )
  if(this.realIndex == 0){
    console.log("first slide do something")
  }
  else{
    console.log("not first slide do somehing")
  }
});
```

`disabled` button related Q:

- [Enable/disable a button in pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176582/enable-disable-a-button-in-pure-javascript/41176769)
- [Disable button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery)

#### Basic Snippet

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    draggable: true,
  }
});

let button = document.getElementById("button")

/* swiper events */
swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
  console.log("slide changed - current slide is: " + this.realIndex )
  if(this.realIndex == 0){
    console.log("first slide do something")
    button.disabled = false;  
  }
  else{
    console.log("not first slide do somehing")
    button.disabled = true;  
  }
});
```

```css
html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<button id="button">Button</button>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before but it didn't work out. Realised I have an old version of Swiper. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

test

```
$('#btn_asd2231').attr('disabled', true);
```

seems to work for me, when I try to disable the button or enable it. Maybe is a bug somewhere else in code.