# Input field and span same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make `<span></span>` same value as `<input>` but I got stuck and code is showing different value

```
function manageSubmitState(){
...
...       

                $("#ecalls").val(calls);
                $("#jobs").val(jobs);
                let _p = Number($("#ppj").val());
                let ROI =  _p * jobs;
                $("#roiVal").html(ROI);
                $(".roi").addClass("visibility");
                $("#calculateBtn").addClass("disableBtn");

                setContentVal(budget, clicks, calls, jobs, _p, ROI);
         });
         $("#ppj, #budget").keyup(function(){
               if($("#ppj").val() == "" || $("#budget").val() == ""){
                   // alert("Button should be dicusbked ")
                    $("#calculateBtn").addClass("disableBtn");
                    
               }
               else{
                $("#calculateBtn").removeClass("disableBtn");
               }
           });

           function setContentVal(_budget, _calls, _jobs, _ppj, _ROI){

            $(".estJobs").text(_jobs);
            $("#ppjTxt").text("$"+_ppj);
            $(".roiTxt").text("$"+_ROI);
            
           }
       })
```

html:

```
<input id="jobs" type="number" disabled="" value="0">
<span class="highlight estJobs" id="estJobs">00</span>
```

It's calculator, after getting input value e.g. 2
in span it shows 1

```
<p>*Now, lets do the math. <span class="highlight estJobs" id="estJobs">3</span> customers times <span class="highlight " id="ppjTxt">$120</span> per job, that makes <span class="highlight roiTxt" id="roiTxt">$120</span> </p>
```

inside roiTxt it should show estJobs * ppjTxt

Comment: Can you combine these into a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `span` to match the input as the `input` is being edited, use the `input` event.

Also, [`disabled` is a Boolean attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176582/enable-disable-a-button-in-pure-javascript/41176769#41176769). Simply being present causes the element to be disabled, there is no value to associate with it, so when you write:

```
disabled=""
```

you are actually disabling the element.

```js
$("#jobs").on("input", function(event){
  $(".estJobs").text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="jobs" type="number" value="0">
<span class="highlight estJobs" id="estJobs">00</span>
```