# What is difference between onbeforeunload in body tag and beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
```

and

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: It's the same thing like you have `onclick()`or `$('el).on('click')`, it's just another way to control the event

Comment: You're missing `return` in the 2nd, so *for other events* (such as click) if `myFunction()` returns false, the first will cancel the event, the 2nd will not cancel the event - this doesn't apply to onbeforeunload as you can't cancel it (thankfully)

Comment: Can't believe there isn't a duplicate of this... There is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905060/what-is-the-difference-between-html-event-attributes-and-assign-events-using-the but it's not perfect...

Answer (score 0):

The **onbeforeunload** event occurs when the document is about to be unloaded.

This event allows you to display a message in a confirmation dialog box to inform the user whether he/she wants to stay or leave the current page shows in below code snippet.

The default message that appears in the confirmation box, is different in different browsers. However, the standard message is something like "Are you sure you want to leave this page?". This message cannot be removed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">

<p>Reload this page, or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Click here to go to stackoverflow.com</a>
    
<script>
function myFunction() {
  return "Write something clever here...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The **beforeunload** event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable at this point.

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a difference in when the function is bound to the event depending on where your jQuery code is. If it's inline in the HEAD section than the jQuery code will run earlier binding the event sooner, otherwise under almost all circumstances the body attribute will bind the function to the event earlier.

Your code probably won't work in modern browsers. This hook is mostly used by less reputable often malicious sites that want to prevent the user from leaving their page and trick them into buying something. Adblockers often prevent the hook in the body tag from firing altogether.

You used to be able to return a string from the function to customize the message but this is now disabled in most browsers. All you can do is confirm that the user wants to leave the page. For future proofing I would put the following code in my head section:

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // ... stuff ...
   return 'reason';
})
</script>
```

Event though there are legitimate, non sketchy reasons to use this event,  I would avoid it unless it's absolutely necessary. There is no guarantee the event will fire and there is a chance that the user clicks the confirm button (or has a setting/extension to always confirm) before your de initialization code has a chance to run.