# Event returns [object MouseEvent] rather than the text

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I have my p tag which suppose to chage text when I trigger mouseover event but somehow I got [object MouseEvent] in return and not the text.

HTML

```
    <p id="album-name-1"
      onmouseover="changeText('follow me around, greatest song of the album!')">
      change the text
    </p>
```

JS

```
      var par = document.querySelector("#album-name-1");

      par.addEventListener("mouseover", changeText);

      function changeText(text) {
        if (this.id === "album-name-1") {
          par.innerHTML = text;
        }
      }
```

I wanted to do this with the use of the **"this"** keyword, but somehow it's not working as I expect it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're adding a `mouseover` event listener with `addEventListener`, and the first parameter of the callback is the event.

Instead, you can pass `this` as a parameter inside the `onmouseover` attribute.

```js
var par = document.querySelector("#album-name-1");

function changeText(elem, text) {
  if (elem.id === "album-name-1") {
    par.innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="album-name-1" onmouseover="changeText(this, 'follow me around, greatest song of the album!')">
  change the text
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use event attributes. They are full of [hard to debug quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497835/3702797) and will bite you someday.

Instead, if you really want to have that text in the markup, store it in a `data-` attribute and retrieve it from your event handler, that you attached through `addEventListener`.

```js
var par = document.querySelector("#album-name-1");

par.addEventListener("mouseover", changeText);

function changeText(evt) { // first param is the Event object
  if (this.id === "album-name-1") { // 'this' is the current target
    // all the data- attributes of our element
    // are stored in its .dataset property
    par.innerHTML = this.dataset.text;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="album-name-1" data-text="follow me around, greatest song of the album!">
  change the text
</p>
```